# How to sum values of specific rows, when conditions apply?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, count, sum

## The Problem

| names | word 1 | word 2 | word 3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doc1 | freq | freq | freq | ... |
| Doc2 | freq | freq | freq | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have an 82 rows x 5k+ columns dataframe in .csv. The columns are words and the rows are documents, the numbers are the frequency these words appear in each document.

I want to **sum the numbers for each row**, applying some conditions. For example, for each row (document), I need to sum **horizontally** the values of columns 10, 15, 100, 1500.

**As a result**, I expect having the total frequency that a list of words appeared in each document.

```
Doc1 = 55
Doc2 = 3
...
```

## What I know and have tried

I'm a beginner coder in Python. I have tried filtering the columns with pandas.dataFrame.loc() but I keep the unintended words also and I'm not able to sum them horizontally. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to sum only 4 columns ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum a list of columns pointed by their index, use `iloc`

```
r = df.iloc[:, [10, 15, 100, 1500]].sum(axis=1)
print(r)
```

If you want to sum a list of columns pointed by their name, use index the dataframe

```
words = ['here', 'elephant', 'car', 'cat'] # whatever your words are
r = df[words].sum(axis=1)
print(r)
```